# how to insert text between two horizontal bars in a stacked bar chart

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to display the four values in the `label` column either **above or below** each horizontal bar. I know how to use `geom_text` (or using `ggrepel`) to display text either to the left or right of the bar, but I can't think of a way to display the text in between bars.

```r
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho", 3), rep("poacee", 3), rep("banana", 3), rep("triticum", 3))
condition <- rep(c("normal", "stress", "Nitrogen"), 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12, 0, 15))
label <- c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4")
data <- data.frame(specie, condition, value)

# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill = condition, y = value, x = specie)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-01-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

So, this is what I expect. Any ideas on how this can be done?

[image]

Comment: As a subjective note, I think a better and clearer visualisation would be achieved using facets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a trick:

```
library(ggplot2)
# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho", 3), rep("poacee", 3), rep("banana", 3), rep("triticum", 3))
condition <- rep(c("normal", "stress", "Nitrogen"), 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12, 0, 15))
label <- c("t1", "t2", "t3", "t4")
data <- data.frame(specie, condition, value)
# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill = condition, y = value, x = specie,label=specie)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  geom_text(aes(y=0.5),position = position_nudge(0.55))+
  coord_flip()
```

Output:

[image]

For sure, your text should be in your dataframe.